# Cannot delete previous plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a graph of predicted function against original function in matplotlib. I have used the following code :

```
import matplotlib as plt

plt.ion()
for i in range(200):
    #Some Operations

    if i%5==0 :
        print(str((i+1))+'th loss',loss.squeeze())
        # plot and show learning process
        plt.cla()
        plt.scatter(x.data.numpy(), y.data.numpy())
        plt.plot(x.data.numpy(), output.data.numpy(), 'r-', lw=5)
        plt.text(0.5, 0, 'Loss=%.4f' % loss.data[0], fontdict={'size': 20, 'color':  'red'})
        plt.pause(0.1)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

On executing this code, the resultant plot does update but it plots over the previous plot even though I have used `cla()` function to clear.
The entire executable code can be found [here](https://github.com/AyushExel/DeepTorch/blob/master/Regression/regression.py).

Comment: There are numerous options and I always google them up. I tend to use `plt.close()` / `plt.clf()` quite often. Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] such that we can reproduce this? Looking at the code along you are right, it should clear the axes.

Comment: @AntonvBR I cannot use plt.close() because the number of iterations can exceed 1000.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have added a link to the executable code